# Como funciona a camada C++ em sistema Web?

Tags: c++, aplicação-web

Vejo que muitos sistemas web complexos dizem em suas APIs que usam C++ como camada "inferior". Como funciona essa camada em C++.

O único exemplo que eu conheço, o Mega [antigo Megaupload] usa essa camada como segurança. Me falaram que a bolsa de valores dos Estados Unidos também usa C++ na camada inferior do sistema web.

Como seria a requisição e resposta?

Quem executaria o *script* C++?

O que o C++ faz, que um Python não consegue fazer por exemplo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O motivo de utilizarem o C, C++ ou até mesmo Assembly é quando precisam de desempenho, não segurança pois essas linguagens dão mais controle do processador, com isso você pode planejar melhor a execução. Mas a menos que seja algo muito específico, dificilmente a gente consegue superar a otimização feita pelo compilador.

Quanto a implementação, varia demais, muitas vezes o pessoal mistura outras linguagens mais comuns (PHP, ASP.Net, etc...) com executáveis externos feitos em C/C++, mas o foco é sempre o desempenho.

Isso não quer dizer fazer um site nessas linguagens vai automaticamente tornar seu site ultra rápido, ASP.Net e PHP possuem um desempenho legal e a menos que você lide com milhões de pedidos por segundo (bolsa de valores como você citou), provavelmente não irá sentir diferença.

Caso ainda queira aprender, existem algumas frameworks para C++:
http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main/

http://www.treefrogframework.org/

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Também é possivel fazer do zero (recomendo apenas se quiser entender como essas frameworks comunicam com o apache ou outro daemon) onde você literalmente responde a pedidos CGI ou FastCGI:

http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/21#S1

http://www.rudeserver.com/vc_tut.html

Answer (score 9):

## Por que ele é bom?

Em essência não existem motivos específicos para usar C++ para *web*. É raro e muita gente divulga isto para fazer propaganda, nem sendo verdade. Então não confie em informações que você não pode verificar.

Claro, existe uma coisa que o C++ faz melhor que quase todas as demais e principalmente faz muito melhor que o Python que você citou: ela é mais rápida! Isto pode ser uma vantagem em muitos cenários, principalmente se comparada com linguagens interpretadas e dinâmicas. Mas o ganho mesmo é a economia de processamento, que se confunde com a velocidade, mas é diferente. Pode ser útil porque é possível atender mais requisições com maior densidade de servidores. Isto gera custos menores, especialmente em nuvem (embora quem quer custo menor não usa nuvem, este é um produto que dá muitas vantagens mas ele custa caro).

Mas se você compara o C++ com o C#, por exemplo, com código bem escrito, boa arquitetura, usando as tecnologias adequadas, é possível obter resultado muito semelhante com mais produtividade, segurança, confiabilidade e robustez.

A velocidade em si não é tão importante porque em geral, mesmo em linguagens mais lentas, o tempo de processamento será menor que o tempo de acesso ao banco de dados e o tempo de transmissão ao cliente. O próprio tempo para mandar da aplicação para o servidor HTTP pode ser muito maior. Pode ajudar um pouco, mas não é essencial. Não estamos falando de algo que terá uma carga tão grande. Muitas vezes o gargalo estará em outro lugar.

Para pegar o exemplo do Mega, eu duvido que eles têm mais processamento que acesso a "disco", que é muito mais lento. O custo de banda deles é tão absurdamente mais caro que eu duvido que compense a economia em servidores que eu acho que eles têm do mesmo jeito para dar conta de tanto disco. E outra, nem eles, e nem a StackExchange (vou falar abaixo) economizam o suficiente para pagar o custo adicional de programadores para ter alta densidade de servidores.

Tem técnicas para tornar até as linguagens de *script* mais rápidas.

Outro grande motivo para se usar C++ é ter um equipe disponível que saiba esta linguagem e não outras. Provavelmente farão algo melhor nela do que em Python que eles nunca viram.

Um motivo para não usar é a falta de infraestrutura na linguagem e biblioteca padrão para trabalhar comi isto. C++ sequer tem uma boa manipulação de *string* para quem mexe muito com isto. Vai precisar desenvolver muita coisa básica ou usar bibliotecas que ajudam, nem todos serão adequados. É bem mais difícil programar em C++, é muito mais fácil cometer erros. Não sei se isso é vantagem, mas para os ingênuos pode ser melhor por ter uma *string* mutável, algumas pessoas podem não perceber que sua linguagem usa uma *string* imutável e em manipulações HTML é comum mexer muito nelas, o que precisa de uma técnica diferente.

Existem algumas outras vantagens como portabilidade, facilidade de implantação, mas que hoje já não é muito verdade mais. Na verdade a necessidade e o tempo de compilação do C++ é tão desvantajoso que a dificuldade de algumas linguagens para implantar (não ocorre mais com C#, por exemplo) é compensada. Algumas linguagens, novamente o C# é um exemplo, mas as linguagens de *stript* costumam ser também bem portáveis. Tanto quanto o C++ se considerar as plataformas *mainstream* onde se usa servidores web.

Eu sou um fanático pela performance e, mesmo assim, admito que C++ para *web* quase sempre é um erro.

É claro que ter uma pequena parte em C++ onde o processamento realmente é muito pesado, pode trazer vantagens, é raro mas acontece. O Mega talvez use algo muito simples que nem dá para dizer que é programação *web*, é algo de infraestrutura. Um servidor HTTP normalmente é escrito em C ou C++, mas isto não é programação *web*, estritamente falando. Uma análise complexa de dados para entregar em uma página pode se beneficiar, mas novamente não podemos chamar isto de programa *web*, a forma como entrega o resultado é *web*, mas e daí? Programação *web* só deve pegar uma requisição, consultar dados, fazer um pequeno processamento para adaptá-lo as necessidades da página, montar a *string* da página e enviar ao servidor HTTP. Se tem que fazer outras coisas mais pesadas não é uma necessidade do sistema *web* em si.

#### Dá para obter mesmo sem C++

Tem algum exemplo de site que fez desta forma? Tem este site aqui. Claro que a versão em português dele sozinho não é muito pesado, mas quando soma todos os sites da rede e principalmente o site original em inglês que originou tudo, verá [o que é possível fazer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/140010). Tem uma [página que dá detalhes](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) e me dá vontade de saber mais. [Mais uma](http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture). Outros [dados defasados](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/) podem ser obtidos em blog de quem mexe com isto.

É só uma pena que eles usem técnicas para economizar processamento que prejudicam a experiência do usuário.

## Como funciona

O conteúdo processado deve ser feito como qualquer outra aplicação. Você vai acessar banco de dados, construir a página com muita manipulação de *strings*, e só vai mudar com a comunicação com o servidor web onde receberá os dados das requisições e enviará a página ou conteúdo (talvez JSON) através de um protocolo, como o [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) ou o [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) ou ainda [ISAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Server_Application_Programming_Interface) se estiver usando Windows.

Hello world "web":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Content-type: text/plain" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/Web.cs).

- Um tutorial básico usando CGI.
- [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) - *framework* que ajuda na maioria das tarefas.
- [CSP](http://www.micronovae.com/CSP.html) - Programação baseada em *templates* (parece abandonado).
- [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main) - CMS completo que serve como um *framework* para desenvolvimento de outras aplicações ou mesmo para adaptar o que precisa.
- [Mais um tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++CGI.html).